# Query dsl update query doesnt't work

Tags: querydsl

I am building a simple update clause

```
SQLUpdateClause updateClause = new SQLUpdateClause(connection, DbUtils.getTemplates(),QCountry.country);

for (Country country : countryList) {
    updateClause.where(qCountry.name.eq(country.getName().trim())
                       .and(qCountry.categoryId.eq(country.getCategoryId())))
                .set(qCountry.currency, country.getCurrency())
                .set(qCountry.sourceOfData, country.getSourceOfData())
                .addBatch();
}
updateClause.execute();
```

If I hard code the value rather than taking it dynamically from the list it does the update. However, I debugged that code and saw that it builds the query with the right values. 
Does anyone have any clue regarding this?

Comment: Which querydsl version and database do you use?

Comment: Query dsl version is 3.4.2 and postgres as a database the  postgresql version is 9.3-1102-jdbc41.

Comment: Could you try Querydsl 3.6.0 as well?